# With awk, how to Insert a number only for lines starting with "Toto" when they are between a specific couple of patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk

With awk, I would like to insert a numbering like `Record n°i#` in front of each line starting with `Toto` only when they are located in-between two specific patterns `start=ABCD` and `stop=EFGH`.

Input file is: (the `Blabla` can be anything in reality)

```
Blabla Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
Toto Blabla
ABCD
Toto Blabla
Toto Blabla
Blabla
Toto Blabla
EFGH
Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
ABCD
Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
Toto Blabla
Toto Blabla
Blabla
EFGH
Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
```

Desired output file is :

```
Blabla Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
Toto Blabla
ABCD
Record n°1#Toto Blabla
Record n°2#Toto Blabla
Blabla
Record n°3#Toto Blabla
EFGH
Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
ABCD
Record n°1#Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
Record n°2#Toto Blabla
Record n°3#Toto Blabla
Blabla
EFGH
Toto Blabla
Blabla Toto
```

I've tried the following script (which must run over bash and gawk v4.0.1), but it doesn't work :

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{indice=1; FS="\n"; RS=""}/^ABCD$/,/^EFGH$/{if(/^Toto/){sub(/^Toto/,"Record n° "indice"\\#Toto"); indice++}print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX `awk`:

```
awk '
  $0 == "ABCD" { n = 1 }
  $0 == "EFGH" { n = 0 }
  /^Toto/ && n { $0 = "Record n°" n++ "#" $0 }
  1
' <file
```

Comment: @Costas: Good point, forgetting to re-factor it. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well cuonglm beat me to it...

```
awk  '/EFGH/{flag=0};
      /ABCD/{flag=1};
      { 
        if (flag && $1=="Toto" && $2=="Blabla"){
          counter++;print "Record n° "counter, $0}
      }' in.txt
```

Or, more compressed:

```
awk '/EFGH/{flag=0};/ABCD/{flag=1};{if (flag&&$1=="Toto"&&$2=="Blabla"){counter++;print "Record n° "counter, $0}}' in.txt
```